# How to implement class constructor in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I just would like to know how to implement class constructor in this language.

Comment: Its important to remember that you can only call methods from an instance of the class when it is public. If the method is private, the only the methods inside of the same class can call it.

Answer (score 98):

Not sure what you mean with "class constructor" but I'd assume you mean one of the ones below.

Instance constructor:

```
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

Shared constructor:

```
Shared Sub New()

End Sub
```

Comment: Class constructor is a VB 6 term for an instance constructor. Alas it is also a OOP term for what you called a shared constructor.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks, I knew it was an ambigious term, but wasn't sure what it meant where. Btw, your answer is slightly wrong in that a `Shared` constructor can't be `Public`.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I get for typing too fast.

Comment: By the way, I just saw a cheat sheet listing `public Foo()` as a "class constructor" in C#. At this point I'm thinking the term is essentially useless.

Comment: If I say "object constructor" or "static constructor" you know exactly what I mean. If I say "class constructor" you have to ask. That makes it useless to me.

Comment: I lost some of my expertise at Visual Basic - been working for long time in C# and JavaScript, etc. I kept trying to use the constructor like you do in C# - but it wasn't working. Some of the differences between VB and C# are annoying.

Answer (score 28):

Suppose your class is called MyStudent. Here's how you define your class constructor:

```
Public Class MyStudent
    Public StudentId As Integer

    'Here's the class constructor:
    Public Sub New(newStudentId As Integer)
        StudentId = newStudentId
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's how you call it:

`Dim student As New MyStudent(studentId)`

Of course, your class constructor can contain as many or as few arguments as you need--even none, in which case you leave the parentheses empty. You can also have several constructors for the same class, all with different combinations of arguments. These are known as different "signatures" for your class constructor.

Answer (score 12):

If you mean VB 6, that would be `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yzhfb2(VS.80).aspx

If you mean VB.NET it is `Public Sub New()` or `Shared Sub New()`.

Answer (score 3):

A class with a field:

```
Public Class MyStudent
   Public StudentId As Integer
```

The constructor:

```
    Public Sub New(newStudentId As Integer)
        StudentId = newStudentId
    End Sub
End Class
```