# Can't Add Model to List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I perform the following `for each` loop to insert models into a list:

```
        Dim weights = weight.Where(Function(x) x.FW_Food_ID = item.NDB_No)

        For Each i In weights
            Dim model = New Tbl_Food_Weight
            model.FW_GmWt = i.FW_GmWt
            Debug.Print("i.FW_GmWt=" + i.FW_GmWt)
            Debug.Print("model.FW_GmWt=" + model.FW_GmWt)
            model.FW_Food_ID = i.FW_Food_ID
            Debug.Print("i.FW_Food_ID=" + i.FW_Food_ID)
            Debug.Print("model.FW_Food_ID=" + model.FW_Food_ID)
            model.FW_Option = i.FW_Option
            Debug.Print("i.FW_Option=" + i.FW_Option)
            Debug.Print("model.FW_Option=" + model.FW_Option)
            model.FW_ID = i.FW_ID
            Debug.Print("i.FW_ID=" + i.FW_ID.ToString)
            Debug.Print("model.FW_ID=" + model.FW_ID.ToString)
            item.test.Add(model)
        Next
```

My model is as follows:

```
Public Class Tbl_Food_Weight

    <Key()> _
    Public Property FW_ID As Integer
    Public Property FW_Food_ID As String
    Public Property FW_Option As String
    Public Property FW_Serving_Size As String
    Public Property FW_GmWt As String

End Class
```

My `test` property is as follows:

```
<NotMapped()> _
Public Overridable Property test As List(Of Tbl_Food_Weight)
```

The output that I get is:

```
i.FW_GmWt=250
model.FW_GmWt=250
i.FW_Food_ID=12695
model.FW_Food_ID=12695
i.FW_Option=1
model.FW_Option=1
i.FW_ID=4481
model.FW_ID=4481
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyBlog.DLL
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
item.test.Add(model)
```

You see, it puts in the variables, but when I go to add the model to the list, it says it's null.  How can I add the model to the list of models?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Item in context:

```
For Each item In food

            Dim weights = weight.Where(Function(x) x.FW_Food_ID = item.NDB_No)
            ... rest of code already posted above
```

Comment: You need to initialize the `test` property in your ctor, just declaring an autobacked property is not enough.

Comment: It could be a null reference on the item, or item.test. Please check the definition of the item and item.test.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

model isn't null -- your test property is.  In the constructor of  whatever item is, you need to "new" your collection.

Comment: How do I "new" the collection?  I updated the question putting `item` in context of how I am using it.

Comment: Nevermind, I added `item.test = New List(Of Tbl_Food_Weight)` to the loop and it seems to have fixed it.  I mistakenly thought this would be done automatically since I defined this already in my model.

Comment: I would not recommend doing it that way.  I would recommend new'ing it in the constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279106/how-to-implement-class-constructor-in-visual-basic an Instance Constructor  where internally you do `Me.test = new List(Of ...)` will ensure that no matter where you create your object, the list `test` will always be ready for use.