# Static class constructor in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is there a way to make a constructor for a `shared` class in VB.NET? I do it all the time in C# as follows, but I can't seem to get it to work in VB.NET.

```
static class someClass
{
    public static string somePublicMember;

    static someClass()
    {
        messageBox.show("I just constructed a static class");
    }
}
```

When the following code is executed, the constructor will be called.

```
...
someSillyClass.someSillyPublicMember = 42;
...
```

Can a `static` (`shared`) class even have a constructor in VB.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement class constructor in Visual Basic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279106/how-to-implement-class-constructor-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a shared class in VB.NET. You have two options:

- use modules. In this case you need some `Init`, which you need to call before anything else.
- use regular classes with Shared methods (my preference), then you can have shared sub new.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. If you use the regular class with shared method, will accessing members automatically call the shared sub new?

Comment: @AppFzx: Yes, that's why I prefer this approach to modules.

Comment: @EhsanUllah looking at it now actually. Both answers address different aspects of the question. Can't accept both answers and this one was up first. I upvoted yours Ehsan

Comment: Modules can also have a constructor, so you do not need to explicitly call an Init Method

Answer (score 28):

Read documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965%28VS.71%29.aspx). In you can do

```
Shared Sub New()
...
End Sub
```

And it will be invoked. From MSDN:

1. Shared constructors are run before any instance of a class type is created.
2. Shared constructors are run before any instance members of a structure type are accessed, or before any constructor of a structure type is explicitly called. **Calling the implicit parameter less constructor created for structures will not cause the shared constructor to run.**
3. Shared constructors are run before any of the type's shared members are referenced.
4. Shared constructors are run before any types that derive from the type are loaded.
5. A shared constructor will not be run more than once during a single execution of a
   program.

Comment: Note that shared constructors are not always run before any instance of a class type is created: on different occasions (e.g. when using COM-Interop), I had to call the shared constructor explicitly and then sometimes, the shared constructor ran twice , though these problems may have been fixed in the newer versions of .NET .

Answer (score 5):

Kind of looks like a normal constructor in VB.NET:

```
Shared Sub New()

End Sub
```

Comment: @AppFzx: there cannot be. [VB.NET does not support it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa2427e3-a57f-4c38-adb9-0496d7e3eb9a/static-class-equivalent-in-vbnet).

Comment: @Neolisk , if you want to repost your answer, I'll accept it. Not sure where it went. I was about to click accept.

Comment: @AppFzx: Got a downvote, so I thought you or somebody else did not like it. Here you go, I put it back.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
Class someClass

    Public Shared somePublicMember As String

    Shared Sub New()
        messageBox.show("I just constructed a static class")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no static/shared classes in VB.net.

There are however Modules that provide similar, thus you will not be able to instantiate them.

Your equivalent code in VB.Net would be (tested using VS2017):

```
Module someClass
    Public somePublicMember As String

    Sub New()
        messageBox.show("I just constructed a static class (not really) [sic]")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: OR use a Class, with nothing but `Shared` members, that has `Shared Sub New()...` and `Private Sub New()...`. This prevents instantiation, and maintains scope. That is, its members must be called via `someClass.somePublicMember`, instead of polluting global name space.

Comment: In order to prevent polluting the global namespace, wrap the Module inside a namespace : module-name. In the above example, this is someClass.